# Number of walks from source to sink with exactly h hops

Tags: algorithm, graph, big-o, breadth-first-search

Given an un-directed graph, a starting vertex and ending vertex. Find the number of walks (so a vertex can be visited more than once) from the source to the sink that involve exactly h hops. For example, if the graph is a triangle, the number of such paths with h hops is given by the h-th [Jakobstahl number](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C3%2C5%2C11%2C21&language=english&go=Search). This can be extended to a fully connected k-node graph, producing the recurrence (and closed form solution) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709109/closed-form-solution-to-recurrence-gn-k-2gn-1k-1gn-2).

When the graph is an n-sided polygon, the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709168/number-of-h-hop-paths-between-two-vertices-with-shortest-path-s-on-an-n-si#3709193) expresses the number of walks as a sum of binomial terms.

I assume there might be an efficient algorithm for finding this number for any given graph? We can assume the graph is provided in adjacency matrix or adjacency list or any other convenient notation.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are actually looking for  number of _paths_ or number of _walks_? In paths, no nodes can be visited twice. In walks, you can visit the same node multiple times. The mention of Jakobstahl number suggests that you want _walks_ instead of paths.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for walks. Edited the question.

Comment: This might become the canonical question for number of walks in a graph. I am surprised this question has not been asked before.

Answer (score 2):

If you take the adjacency matrix of a graph and raise it to the nth power, the resulting matrix counts the number of paths from each node to each other that uses exactly n edges. That would provide one way of computing the number you want - plus many others you aren’t all that interested in. :-)

Assuming the number of paths is “small” (say, something that fits into a 64-bit integer), you could use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to compute the matrix in O(log n) multiplies for a total cost of O(|V|<sup>ω</sup> log n), where ω is the exponent of the [fastest matrix multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm). However, if the quantity you’re looking for doesn’t fit into a machine word, then the cost of this approach will depend on how big the answer is as the multiplies will take variable amounts of time. For most graphs and small n this won’t be an issue, but if n is large and there are other parts of the graph that are densely connected this will slow down a bit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, thanks. Didn't know about that adjacency matrix raised to power property. Seems like it was made for this question. Do you have a link to a proof?

Comment: I don't have a ready-to-use proof of this, but here's a quick sketch of an inductive argument. Let A be the adjacency matrix for the graph. The matrix A^0 is the identity matrix, indicating that there's one path from each node to itself of length zero. Now assume that A^k counts the number of paths of length exactly k from each node to each other node. Now think about A^{k+1} = A^kA and look at the entry at position (i, j). This is the product of the ith row of A^k and jth column of A. The ith row of A^k counts length-k paths from node i to each othe rnode. The jth col of A counts length-1...

Comment: paths from each node to node j. This therefore counts ways to get from i to some node x in k hops and then from x to j in one hop, summed over all nodes k. That's the number of paths from i to j of length k+1.

Comment: This is correct, but would benefit from the use of right terminologies. It should be called _walks_ (can visit the same node) instead of _paths_ (no repeat of node in a path).

Comment: For proofs, there are lots of it online. Good luck!

Comment: And thanks templatetypedef for the answer! Do you think it would be useful to add the details of the log n algo here? I didn't find it on other questions (I might miss it), and this question could be the canonical question and answer for the number of walks in a graph

Comment: Regarding the overall runtime-complexity: matrix-multiplication is `O(n^3)`, if implemented the naive way. The fastest algorithm is `O(n^2.373)` for `n x n` matrices. So the overall complexity would be `O(|V|^2.373 * log n)` in the best case.

Comment: @Paul Good catch. This will be better for higher h and lower V then.

Comment: @Paul Good catch - fixed!

Answer (score 2):

A solution to this would be to use a modified BFS with two alternating queues and a per-node counter for paths to this node of a certain length:

```
paths(start, end, n):
    q = set(start)
    q_next = set()
    path_ct = map()
    path_ct_next = map()

    path_ct[start] = 1

    for i in [0, n):  # counting loop
        for node in q:  # queue loop
            for a in adjacent(node):  # neighbor-loop
                path_ct_next[a] += path_ct[node]
                q_next.add(a)

        q = q_next
        q_next = set()

        path_ct = path_ct_next
        path_ct_next = map()

   return path_ct_next[end]
```

The basic assumption here is that `map()` produces a dictionary that returns zero, if the entry doesn't yet exist. Otherwise it returns the previously set value. The counting-loop simply takes care of doing exactly as many iterations as hops as required. The queue loop iterates over all nodes that can be reached using exactly `i` hops. In the neighbor-loop finally all nodes that can be reached in `i + 1` hops are found. In this loop the adjacent nodes will be stored into a queue for the next iteration of counting-loop. The number of possible paths to reach such a node is the sum of the number of paths to reach it's predecessors. Once this is done for each node of the current iteration of counting-loop, the queues and tables are swapped/replaced by empty instances and the algorithm can start over.

Comment: OP just clarified that they wanted walks instead of paths. In that case, this method will be too expensive.

Comment: @justhalf why too expensive? We're at `O(n * |V|)`. You'll have a rather hard time beating that bound. But I've just noticed that this algorithm is for walks, not paths anyways, since I forgot to add a visited-check.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I was confusing myself when I made that comment. Apologies. Note that, however, the complexity is at `O(n |V|^2)`, since the number of neighbor (when doing the neighbor-loop) can be as high as n. So your answer is good for lower n (about 1mio?) but high V (about 10k nodes) compared to the other answer which is better for high n (billions) but slightly lower V (2k-ish, assuming V^3 matrix multiplication). This is because your answer finds the answer only for the target node (which is what the question asks for), while the other answer does for all nodes.

Comment: @justhalf right, I completely missed out on the loop over all neighboring nodes. That makes the whole algorithm `O(n |V|^2)`. Thanks for the correction. Might be better to state it as `O(n |E|)` anyways, since we're dealing with edges rather than vertices anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an algorithm that keep searching all possible paths , but with a variable that will contain your number of hops

For each possible path , each hop will decrement that variable and when arriving to zero your algorithm goes to trying another path , and if ever a path arrives to the target before making variable reachs zero , this path will be added to the list of your desired paths

Comment: So, like a depth first search? How would we know when to stop?

Comment: it will test all possible paths , so it will stop when they finish , is that your question ?

Comment: I think you want the target node to be visited exactly when the counter is zero. Also, I believe this will take exponential time, so, not practical.